# How to obtain antiderivative numerically with known partial derivative matrices using MATLAB?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab

assuming an unknown original function is $f(x,y)$, now I have its partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ expressed by two matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$. How can I get the original function matrix $f(x,y)$ numerically? I am using MATLAB.

In other words, if I have artificially generated two matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, how can I obtain the/an original function whose partial derivatives are $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$?

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of **inverse gradient**. It is famous and not so easy.

You can express the problem with linear algebra by trying to find a way to (vec)torize A and B and find numerical approximation matrices for the partial differential operators to finally solve

$$\min_C \{\|D_x vec(C) - vec(A)\| + \|D_yvec(C) - vec(B)\|\}$$

Where $D_x$, $D_y$ are matrices representing partial differentiation w.r.t. x and y, respectively

As the system is underdetermined (constant levels are free) you will do well to add some term of **regularization**. This is good practice or even necessary for many problems of the differential equation kind.